# Is it acceptable to ask or present a recommendation letter from a professor who left the university?

Tags: masters, recommendation-letter

I finished my undergraduate studies around 2 and a half years ago. I didn't directly apply to any university to continue my master's degree.

Recently, I decided to continue. I live in Lebanon and I was searching for some universities in the UK to apply for. I found some local agents that help students with their inquiries. They asked me to provide them with 2 academic recommendation letters or either 1 academic and 1 professional.

If anyone saw [my answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/108387/is-it-appropriate-to-email-a-professor-saying-you-enjoyed-their-class-after-doi/108403#108403) around here would know that I am still in contact with one of my professors back in the university. That professor now left this university and even left the country with his family, yet we're still in touch.

My question is the next:

Is it academically appropriate to ask him for a recommendation letter? In case he did write me one, would it be legit to present it since he left the university?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes he can give you a reference.

But he can’t say he is still at X university , it has to be clear he has moved on just in case they try to contact him.

People move all the time...

Some universities still receive reference requests for professors who are no longer available (death, no contact etc) and organize another professor or the Dean to write a reference to help the student.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he can write a reference for you, outlining how and when he knew you as a student at his former institution, signing it with his current title at his current institution.  Happens all the time.

Comment: Mentioning that he was formerly _a professor_ at the student's institution.

Comment: @Buffy  That's the "how" he knew the student.

Comment: Yes, but I think it should be explicit. It is possible to know a student otherwise, of course. The OP isn't in control of what is said, however.

Comment: @Buffy If indeed he actually held a professor title, I'm pretty sure he will know how to write an LOR.  I'm only a lecturer and I know how to do it.